# Determine if window is active in webkit

Tags: javascript, css, macos, webkit, titanium

Is there some css selector or something of the like that allows you to apply different styles to elements in an inactive page/window in webkit? There is for scrollbars: http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/
I'm using this to make a Titanium desktop application feel more native on Mac OS X.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus

> These events work in every major
>   browser (Firefox, Internet Explorer
>   6/7, Safari & Opera).

Demo: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/demo/2007-05-16-detect-browser-window-focus/

```
function onBlur() {
    document.body.className = 'blurred';
};
function onFocus(){
    document.body.className = 'focused';
};

if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}
```

Comment: You'd think there would be something that could do it, there is for scrollbars, why not other things? Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I changed my answer after checking Google. It turns out there is a way after all. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Since you is focusing only WebKit, you theoricaly could use `:window-inactive` pseudo-selector, which is supposed to work with scrollbars. I haven't tested it on MacOS X, but you can try it.

But if you want something more cross-browser, use JavaScript to define a CSS class based on the window activity. See this thread: [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Comment: I didn't notice that question you've linked. It's got exactly the same accepted answer as my answer here. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately `:window-inactive` is not standardized and only works on scrollbars and text selection using `::selection` as far as I know.  You'd have to use javascript to get what you want.